# How to make the screen scroll while using the iPhone keypad

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm working on an app that is in landscape view. I'm using a few UITextFields that when double tapped it will give you the ability to edit the TextFields. My question is how do I get the screen to scroll so the user can edit entire screen while the keypad is shown?

Comment: please go through the below post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `contentInset` and `scrollRectToVisible` has served me well. The code below insets the scroll view so it is not covered by the keyboard, and then scrolls the content to display the  the text field.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    CGRect kbFrame;
    [[aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&kbFrame];                    
    float kbHeight = [self convertRect:kbFrame fromView:nil].size.height;               
    float d = kbHeight - self.frame.origin.y / self.transform.a;        
    d = d < 0 ? 0 : d;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, d, 0.0);

    self.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    UIView *responder = /* ... your text field ... */
    [self scrollRectToVisible:responder.frame animated:YES];        
    [self performSelector:@selector(flashScrollIndicators) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;

    [[aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration 
                          delay:0 
                        options:animationCurve
                     animations:^{
                         self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
                         self.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;                      
                     } 
                     completion:nil];

    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES]; 
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: UIView *responder = ? tex2... Could you give an example putting the textField?

Comment: Just do `UIView *responder = theTextField`, where `theTextField` is your text field. The reason is on the next line which fetches the size (frame) of the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use uitextfield delegate method.

```
`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    self.view.center=CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+60);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    self.view.center=CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-60);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

}
  `

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer the solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present). Basically you need to move your scrollview by amounts so that your text field is visible. In yout textfieldbeginediting call the method below.

```
- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGRect keyboardBounds = CGRectMake(0, 280, 320, 200);
    CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height;    // Remove area covered by keyboard

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;
    if (y < 0) {
        y = 0;
    }
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(applicationFrame.size.width, applicationFrame.size.height + keyboardBounds.size.height);
    [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];
}
```